# Pass variable to define() php

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

Does anyone know how to use the define function and pass a variable into it? Maybe I'm doing this wrong altogether? I have setup some options in WordPress Settings API, and am trying to pass the option value into my plugin.

What am I doing wrong?

```
define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
$options = get_option('plugin_options');
var $gMapKey = $options['map_key'];
define("KEY", $gMapKey);
```

Comment: What's not working? Perhaps you just have a misplaced `var` keyword?

Comment: When I try to define the "KEY" with the php var - i get a blank page.

Comment: Are you sure get_option() is returning expected values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var is meant for classes, you should be using:

```
$gMapKey = $options['map_key']
```